# LibGDX FitViewport doesn't work anymore after Google Play Games Overlay

Tags: android, libgdx

I have an Android game that uses FitViewport so that aspect ratio is always correct (showing black bars as necessary). Everything has been working fine with my previous few phones.

However, now I got a new one, Samsung Galaxy J6. With this phone, after I display, for example, Google Play Games achievements activity, and then return back to the LibGDX activity, the black bars are gone and the FitViewport is effectively not working at all (everything is scaled). Does anyone have ideas why displaying a "native" Android activity on top of the LibGDX activity "breaks" the FitViewport?

Answer (score 1):

Oh well. I was simply missing this:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```